# R: Nested for-loop to compare rows and build new data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, compare, comparison

#### I created two nested for loops to complete the following:

Iterating through each column that is not the first column:

- Iterate through each row i that is NOT the last row (the last row is denoted j)
- Compare the value in i to the value in j.

  - If i is NA, i = NA.
  - If i >= j, i = 0.
  - If i < j, i = 1.

Store the results of all iterations across all columns and rows in a df.

#### The code below creates some test data but produces a Value "out" that is NULL (empty). Any recommendations?

```
# Create df
a <- rnorm(5)
b <- c(rnorm(3),NA,rnorm(1))
c <- rnorm(5)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)

rows <- nrow(df)  # rows
cols <- ncol(df)  # cols

out <- for (c in 2:cols){
          for (r in 1:(rows - 1)){
            ifelse(
                    is.na(df[r,c]),
                    NA,
                    df[r, c] <- df[r, c] < df[rows, c])
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for looping at all. Use a vectorised function like `sweep` to compare via `>` your last row - `df[nrow(df),]` vs all the other rows `df[-nrow(df),]`:

```
df
#           a          b           c
#1 -0.2739735  0.5095727  0.30664838
#2  0.7613023 -0.1509454 -0.08818313
#3 -0.4781940  1.5760307  0.46769601
#4  1.1754130         NA  0.33394212
#5  0.5448537  1.0493805 -0.10528847

sweep(df[-nrow(df),], 2, unlist(df[nrow(df),]), FUN=`>`)
#      a     b    c
#1 FALSE FALSE TRUE
#2  TRUE FALSE TRUE
#3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
#4  TRUE    NA TRUE

sweep(df[-nrow(df),], 2, unlist(df[nrow(df),]), FUN=`>`) + 0
#  a  b c
#1 0  0 1
#2 1  0 1
#3 0  1 1
#4 1 NA 1
```

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around this but the example with "+ 0" does not produce the result shown. I just tried it on a df with NAs and the NAs turn to 0. Correction?

Comment: @user3614648 - it works fine for me using `df` as you supplied above. I can't fathom any way that `NA + 0 == 0` - here is a simple example: `data.frame(a=c(1,NA),b=1:2) + 0` the `NA` does not change.

Comment: Realized I had NaNs and not NAs.

Comment: @user3614648 - `NaN + 0` returns `NaN`, so no `0` there either.

Comment: I have no idea what caused this. I had a data frame named x where is.list(x) and is.data.frame(x) both were TRUE. Print(x) showed NaNs in some cells and view(x) showed NA in those cells. I tried x[is.nan(x)] <- NA to set the NaNs to NA and received "method not implemented for type 'list'". My resolution was to use x[is.na(x)] <- NA and then use the solution above with sweep(). The values that had mistakenly turned to 0 were now NAs. No idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option.  We can replicate the last row to make the dimensions of both datasets equal and then do the `>` to get a logical index, which can be coerced to binary by wrapping with `+`.

```
+(df[-nrow(df),] > df[nrow(df),][col(df[-nrow(df),])])
#  a  b c
#1 0  0 1
#2 1  0 1
#3 0  1 1
#4 1 NA 1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "replicate the last row to make the dimensions of both datasets equal?" I do not quite understand the logic of this approach...and it does not work due to the dimensions not matching.

Comment: @user3614648  Based on the data showed in the @thelatemail's post, I am getting the exact result.  I works because we are replicating each element in the last row by the number of rows of the `df[-nrow(df),]`